# What is the security measure that prevents me from posting using script and I must use browser to execute HTTP POSTs successfully

Tags: http, python

I'm using python to log into kijiji.ca with cookies enabled. The login is successful and passes (verified). I then use python to post an ad, however the ad posting keeps failing and redirects me to the login page (as if my username and password is wrong) 
What is preventing me from posting properly? I've made sure form values are filled out properly in my posting. 
Is there some security measure that prevents me from posting using my python script and I must go through the browser?

Comment: You should prolly start with curl + local proxy to make sure that you actually do need a browser

Answer (score 2):

Typically such failures are caused by

1. Bugs in your program.
2. The site requiring Javascript which your python program probably does not handle.
3. Or the detection of non-browser user-agents on the site.

The most common cases are probably 1. and 2. (which are unrelated to information security) while 3. might be employed by sites which explicitly forbid automatic submissions or have special API's for this in place.

Comment: I think it's #2. How can i confirm it's #2? My script has been working for months and it stop working recently due to a change in their website security. I am using user-agents when connected via python ie. my http requests/pots look like it's from a browser: 'user-agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; rv:42.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/42.0',

Comment: @user1144251: use wireshark or the built-in tools in the browser to look at the actual requests which are sent by the client and compare. The request from your program must look the same as the request from the browser.

Comment: I've verified what I send is fine the cookies however don't seem to match up. When i'm at the posting page, the cookie from my script is 1/2 the size for the same cookie on the posting page when I use the browser.

Comment: However I have successfully logged in using my script and I have cookies enabled. I think this problem has to do with cookies because when I fail to post, it brings me back to the login screen. Previously before the security changes, it brought me to the home page however I'm still logged in. But now, I'm redirected to the login screen and i'm no longer logged in. So this seems to me to be cookie related but I have no idea how the cookies are set as I use some automatic cookie jar inside python to handle all cookies...

Answer (score 0):

Try adding Browser Useragents (try to fool the application making it believe you use browser!). I have seen google preventing non-browser requests. So like @steffen said, if it is 2/3 try hacking it this way. !